# What format do we need to use to get the Suggested Action Items feature to work?

Tags: google-docs

Google [mentions](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/65129) the following about the suggested action items feature:

> As you type, if Google Docs detects an action item (for example, “AI: Jen to send a follow-up email” or “Todo: Alex to finish the presentation”), a suggested action item will appear.
>
> ...
>
> For action items to be suggested, the text must:
>
> - Mention someone’s name or email.
> - Mention someone with access to the file.

I find that I can only reliably create an action item 50% of the time, even after reading those suggestions above. Is there any more guidance for how to ensure that whatever text I write will be picked up as an action item?

For example, what format does it expect the sentence to be in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Don't use the new @ mention feature

They recently released a new [@ mention feature](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2020/10/mention-a-user-directly-in-google-docs.html) to tag people in documents.

You cannot use this with the suggested action items feature. Instead, you should type out the person's name or email address normally.

### 2. Sentence should include an identifier (`TODO` or `AI`):

The most reliable identifiers are `TODO` and `AI`.

`TO DO` and `ACTION ITEM` sometimes work, but may require the next rule below.

Works:

```
AI: Charlie to send the email.
Todo: Charlie to send the email.

ai: Charlie to send the email.              # Identifiers are case-insensitive.
TODO: Charlie to send the email.            # Identifiers are case-insensitive.
AI Charlie to send the email.               # `:` is not required.
Charlie to send AI the email.               # It's OK for the identifier to occur anywhere in the sentence.

TO DO: Charlie to send the email.           # Not recommended because "to" is critical here.
Action Item: Charlie to send the email.     # Not recommended because "to" is critical here.
```

Doesn't work:

```
Charlie to send the email.               # Missing an identifier (e.g. "TODO").
TO DO: Charlie send the email.           # The word "to" is missing, or "TODO" should have been used.
Action Item: Charlie send the email.     # The word "to" is missing, or "AI" should have been used.
```

### 3. Sentences should include the word "to".

Especially when using one of the less reliable identifiers (e.g. `TO DO` or `Action Item`), including the word "to" makes it more likely your phrase will be picked up.

Works:

```
TODO: Charlie send the email.               # Since we're using the more reliable identifier, "to" is not necessary.
AI: Charlie send the email.                 # Since we're using the more reliable identifier, "to" is not necessary.

TO DO: Charlie to send the email.           # Including the word "to" causes this to be picked up.
Action Item: Charlie to send the email.     # Including the word "to" causes this to be picked up.
```

Doesn't work:

```
TO DO: Charlie send the email.           # Either use "TODO", or add the word "to".
Action Item: Charlie send the email.
```

### Other notes

- Sometimes there are weird oddities with names which can't easily be explained. For example, "AI: Charlie to foo" and "AI: Charlie foo" were both recognized. However, "AI: Derek to foo" was NOT recognized, but "AI: Derek foo" was recognized. Finally, "AI: Jose to foo" was recognized while "AI: Jose foo" was NOT recognized.
- Sometimes there are weird oddities between documents. For example, in one document "AI: Charlie to send the email" might work, but in another it might NOT. This is despite both documents being shared with the same group. Sometimes this discrepancy can even occur with your own name. One workaround is to use full email addresses.
- It can take a few seconds before the sentence is recognized.
- If you're copying/pasting, you might need to modify the sentence for it to be analyzed. (e.g. delete and retype the `.` or any of the words).